# How to get unique records from Active Record rails 4 based on a column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have following models

Customer

Payments: customer_id, customer_sign_up, :more_columns

Now I want one payment per customer_id.. Please remember I have many records, and I need a good performance / best way to do this.

This only gets me customer_ids:

```
Payment.unscoped.where(:customer_sign_up => 1.year.ago..Date.today).uniq.pluk(:customer_id)
```

This did not work either:

```
# #Payment.unscoped.where(params[:type].to_sym => 
      #               Date.parse(params[:start])..Date.parse(params[:end])
      #             ).group(["customer_id", "payments.id"]).order("customer_id desc").select("DISTINCT(customer_id), payments.*")
```

I want entire rows of payment.

Added from comment:
I dont want only one payment. But one payment per customer_id:

Payments: amount, sign_up, customer_id

Each customer can have many payments.
And each customer will have many payments for sure.

And I dont want to search on customer but rather on payments and filter out the records there.

Answer (score 0):

```
customer.payments.where(:customer_sign_up => 1.year.ago..Date.today).order("created_at.desc").first
```

I've gone for the most recent here with the order field, you can adjust that to whatever you want to use as the criteria for choosing a single payment.

Comment: I dont want only one payment. But one payment per customer_id:

Payments: amount, sign_up, customer_id

Each customer can have many payments.
And each customer will have many payments for sure.

And I dont want to search on customer but rather on payments and filter out the records there.

Hope this makes more sense